# How does 'as to' mean 'with respect to'?

Tags: meaning

I already understand and so ask NOT about the definition, which I instead want to burrow into.

> [as to](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as-to?q=as+to) = With respect to; concerning:

How does the juxtaposition of **as** + **to** effect/imply/produce this meaning, which neither word seems to possess alone?

Answer (score 1):

> as to = With respect to; concerning:

*As for* me, I simply perceive this compound preposition as a shortening of:

> **As** we turn **to** ...

An [example](http://books.google.ru/books?id=6tNVzsD8ajQC&lpg=PA47&dq=%22as%20we%20turn%20to%22&hl=ru&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q=%22as%20we%20turn%20to%22&f=false):

> **As we turn to** the subject of manners and courtesy, this verse has much to offer us.

Comment: The first reasonable hypothesis I read as to the development of this curious compound preposition.

Answer (score 0):

It's just one of those things in English; sometimes if you combine two words you get a phrase that has a different meaning than each word by itself. When I think of another example, I'll edit my post.

I would note that *as to* is okay to use, but it less preferable than *concerning* or *regarding*. (One of my coworkers from Romania likes to use "related to" — as in "Related to the initialization code, we need to add something to detect errors" — and it's perfectly understandable, but not natural-sounding, and I haven't got the heart to tell him this.)