# the difference 'to' and 'as to'

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning, as

> a suggestion or proposal **as to** the best course of action, especially one put forward by an authoritative body.

If I change **as to** to **to**, as this:

> a suggestion or proposal **to** the best course of action, especially one put forward by an authoritative body

What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: Use either ***as to*** or ***for*** (or feasibly ***regarding***) in your cited context. Plain ***to*** isn't idiomatic here.

Comment: Note that terms like ***regarding, concerning*** (and maybe even ***as to***) may imply a looser relationship than ***for*** (i.e. - a suggestion ***concerning*** the best course of action might not actually *be* something considered to be the best course of action). It might, for example, be someone proposing a mechanism for choosing between the available alternative suggestions. But that's only a *possible* distinction, that wouldn't normally apply (normally all prepositional elements here would be interpreted the same).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "As For" and "As To".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46168/difference-between-as-for-and-as-to) Also ["As for" replaced by concerning/as to in a context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184009/) and [How does 'as to' mean 'with respect to'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38908/) and [Using "regarding the" instead of "as to the"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72567/) and ["As to something" vs "as for something"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27720/) among others. (It's a very popular question! :)

Comment: They answer different questions, but serve as a good resource of suppliment knowledge. My question was, more specifically, **as to** and **to** sometimes could be interchangeable and the sentence has no significant change in meaning, though the two words are different. Now I can roughly know their difference, but maybe I need to get more experience to use it precisely.

Comment: I don't really get your "Now I can roughly know their difference". The difference between ***as to*** and ***to*** in your examples is as pointed out in my first comment. The two-word form is perfectly idiomatic, but the single word preposition ***to*** isn't (but ***for*** is). That's all there is to understand.

Comment: You are right. To be more precise, either **to** or **as to** are acceptable in the above sentences. In fact, I know their difference. But if I write sentences using them, I'm faced with choosing more precise one. It's more a matter of experience

Comment: ***NO**!* - It's ***not*** true that "either to or as to are acceptable in the above sentences". The single-word preposition ***to*** is not idiomatically valid here, as pointed out by the answer you yourself upvoted!

Comment: Then how about this one: **a question to your answer** and **a question as to your answer**, how do you comprehend the two phrases? Do you think they have nearly same meaning? My first sense of their meaning is: (there is) a question about your answer. But I then find it seems the correct form is: a question to sb. I don't know, maybe I have been wrongly understanding **to**. According to my experience, the usage of **to** is too varied and error-prone. I have never been able to totally grasp usage of these prepositions.

Comment: ***a question to your answer*** doesn't really mean anything to me (I can't see how to include those words in a valid sentence, and I've no idea what it's *supposed* to refer to). ***a question as to your answer*** is confusing, because the construction *[There is] **a question as to X*** is normally used in contexts where ***X*** represents a ***decision / choice*** (or the need to make that choice), as in *There is a question as to whether to do that*. Effectively, *There is a question as to X* normally means *There is [room for] debate **regarding** X* (i.e. - *X is not necessarily true*).

Comment: I can't totally clear some confusion in my head, which is now I know what you mean but don't know why it's wrong. Many sentences with full context would be much helpful, that's the main way I learn English. I think I need to read more to make it clear. Your replies provide valuable information, revealing the problem. Thanks for your patient answering. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: ***The answer to your question*** is perfectly normal English, formed in the same way as, say, ***The road to the city***. In both cases the noun after ***to*** is something very closely linked (cause, source, outcome,...) to the first noun - and that *combination* of the two nouns *in that relationship* is meaningful. But ***The question to your answer*** and ***The city to the road*** are not meaningful concepts in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As to" means regarding, a meaning which isn't expressed by "to" alone.